# Automating Visual Studio 2012 with Powershell, doing it wrong?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, envdte

I was exploring Visual Studio automation with powershell. At least from what I can find, it seems that powershell is the thing to use to automate visual studio.

```
$dte = New-Object -ComObject VisualStudio.DTE
```

The above line, I see creates a new Visual Studio 10 denenv.exe in process monitor, and then also a warning is thrown about not being able to create the object.

```
WARNING: Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {656D8328-93F5-41A7-A48C-B42858161F25} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80010001.
```

It seems like maybe since there is a delay, that may be there is a timeout. This CLSID is for the visual studio 10 DTE, and it appears there is not DTE for 2012.

Can I create a Visual Studio 2012 instance at all? Or does this matter? Or am I approaching this all wrong?

All I really want to do is create a solution, and then traverse a directory to add all of the .csproj files I can find. I have repository of about 70 odd projects that I'd like to put in a mega solution. This powershell solution, seems like it may not be the best way anymore.

Definitely could have had this done now if I'd just done this manually, but I thought this was an interesting exploratory exercise but it's just becoming a headache now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this AddIn should suit my need: [Solution Maker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/48b12951-a351-4341-bc1f-474f2f468053?SRC=VSIDE)