# Can Visual Studio 2012 be automated using cmdlets?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2012, powershell-cmdlet

I was curious if this could be done using PowerShell.

Personally, what I would like to automate: is adding an existing Local IIS website to a solution

I saw one person tried to do this using COM, but apparently without any luck.
[Automating Visual Studio 2012 with Powershell, doing it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733896/automating-visual-studio-2012-with-powershell-doing-it-wrong)

Comment: When you mention COM, do you mean the EnvDTE? (`[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("visualstudio.dte.11.0")`)

Comment: Someone advised [StudioShell](http://studioshell.codeplex.com/) project in my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156984/recursively-traversing-a-visual-studio-solution-using-powershell I haven't tried it out yet, but taking a look it looks promising!

Comment: Csaba, I have no idea :)

Answer (score 2):

You can automate Visual Studio 2012 with PowerShell.  The Package Manager Console is actually a PowerShell host.  From the Package Manager Console, the variable $dte is the COM automation object that you use to automate most of Visual Studio.

See http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/using-nuget-powershell-to-replace-missing-macros-in-dev-11 for more details and some examples.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but for those still interested in this...

There's actually not that much code involved in writing your own cmdlet to acquire a COM binding of a DTE object for use in PowerShell scripts.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39627967/1801144) on a related question for the source code of a working `Get-DTE ...` cmdlet.  Once you have the DTE binding it's pretty much the same process as all the examples you've likely seen elsewhere.

#### Example:

```
PS C:\> Import-Module .\GetDTECmdlet.dll;
PS C:\> $dte = Get-DTE | Select-Object -First 1;
PS C:\> $dte = Get-DTE -ProcID 8547 | Select-Object -First 1;
PS C:\> $dte = Get-DTE -FromAncestorProcs | Select-Object -First 1;
PS C:\> $dte.ExecuteCommand('Help.About');
PS C:\> [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($dte); | Out-Null;
```

The source code for the cmdlet is probably a bit overkill unless you were wanting access to the DTE from a pre/post-build step like I was.  But, it should be sufficient to get you started.

And, if you really want to avoid digging into building your own cmdlet, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39599492/1801144) on the same question which essentially wraps the C# code from the cmdlet in a PowerShell `Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"..."@` command so that you don't need `GetDTECmdlet.dll` at all.